# Issue with rewriting using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess for better URLs.

I have this php page:

treatments-line.php

With

```
#rewrite treatments-line
RewriteRule ^/?treatments/line/([0-9]+)$ treatments-line.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I can successfully enter the page /treatments/line/the_id_of_the_page.

But when I create a page treatments.php, the rewrite of treatments-line doesn't work, it simply shows the frontpage.

For a test when I change the rewrite method into this:

```
#rewrite treatments-line
RewriteRule ^/?treatment/line/([0-9]+)$ treatments-line.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I've just changed the name into treatment (without "s"), the rewrite on /treatment/line/the_id_of_the_page works fine, but I don't want to change the name.

So, I can see that there's a conflict with the name, because of treatments.php file.

How can I fix that?

These two PHP pages are in root directory of the website.

EDIT2:

Here's my whole .htaccess code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 

#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} /(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.php [NC,L]

#redirect posts-view
RewriteRule ^/?post/([0-9]+)$ posts-view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-zone
RewriteRule ^/?products/zone/([0-9]+)$ products-zone.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-category
RewriteRule ^/?products/category/([0-9]+)$ products-category.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-solution
RewriteRule ^/?products/solution/([0-9]+)$ products-solution.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-line
RewriteRule ^/?products/line/([0-9]+)$ products-line.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite treatments-line
RewriteRule ^/?treatments/line/([0-9]+)$ treatments-line.php?id=$1 [NC,L]    

#rewrite treatments-category
RewriteRule ^/?treatments/category/([0-9]+)$ treatments-category.php?id=$1 [NC,L]   

#rewrite product-view
RewriteRule ^/?products/([0-9]+)$ product-view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#redirect lang
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]

#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You have two files called `treatments-line.php` and `treatments.php` and you want to have the same rewrite url pattern for both?

Comment: No, these two pages have different content. I only want to rewrite url pattern the treatments-line.php.

Comment: Yeah. It's because of `treatments.php`.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Comment: You want to have the same URL and also the `treatments.php`?

Comment: I want treatments.php to be the same, but treatments-line.php to have url /treaments/line/the_id_of_the_page

Comment: Right now, there's a conflict between them. Maybe .htaccess has additional function to avoid that issue...

Comment: Why don't you just do a 301 redirect and give it a pretty name  the file people and bots will still find it and you wont have to have any wacky rewrites in htaccess unless you want it to appear as if line is a different directory..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?treatments/line/([0-9]+)$ treatments-line.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Adding `Options -MultiViews` solves you the issue.

For more information about `Options -MultiViews`:

> A MultiViews search is enabled by the MultiViews Options. If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews

Based on your .htaccess code and also the comments, you need to change the position of the `#remove .php` rule to the very end of the .htaccess. So, this is how your .htaccess code should be like:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 

#redirect posts-view
RewriteRule ^/?post/([0-9]+)$ posts-view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-zone
RewriteRule ^/?products/zone/([0-9]+)$ products-zone.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-category
RewriteRule ^/?products/category/([0-9]+)$ products-category.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-solution
RewriteRule ^/?products/solution/([0-9]+)$ products-solution.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite products-line
RewriteRule ^/?products/line/([0-9]+)$ products-line.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#rewrite treatments-line
RewriteRule ^/?treatments/line/([0-9]+)$ treatments-line.php?id=$1 [NC,L]    

#rewrite treatments-category
RewriteRule ^/?treatments/category/([0-9]+)$ treatments-category.php?id=$1 [NC,L]   

#rewrite product-view
RewriteRule ^/?products/([0-9]+)$ product-view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

#redirect lang
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]

#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've added `Options -MultiViews`, but it still doesn't work, even I've cleared the cache from the browser. If I rename the treatments.php into treatment.php, the rewrite works.

Comment: I had the same issue initially. I tried to pass the URL like `http://localhost/treatments/line/2` and then it worked. Initially it was `http://localhost/treatments/line/1`. This one didn't work even when I cleared the cache and opening new tab and passing the same URL. Finally I changed the number in the URL to 2 and it worked. I'm not sure what was that creating such issue. Maybe clearing the cache or closing the whole browser itself can resolve the issue.

Comment: I've tried that too with different numbers, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you post me the whole `.htaccess` code you have?

Comment: I've just edited my main thread. Please check. I've also tried by closing the whole browser, but it's still the same.

Comment: Yeah. Checking out. You added a rule for `remove .php`. Is that because of this issue or you have your own purpose to do that?

Comment: No, I usually use that for removing the .php.

Comment: Wow, I cant believe...that was the issue. I've commented the lines for removing the .php and now finally rewriting works fine.

Comment: Oh. That's great. I was thinking why you would do that without a solid reason because you said you would usually add `#remove .php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130905/discussion-between-perumal93-and-user2519032).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Options -MultiViews` is the only way that could resolve your issue. That's why I wanted to make sure few things from you by asking the whole `.htaccess` code.

Comment: Yes, I've commented it, but now I cannot enter the pages without using .php and that's very important feature.

Comment: What are you use it for?

Comment: I'm using it for urls without .php. For an example the page is /treatments and now when I've commented that function, the page wont work. I have to enter it like this /treatments.php.

Comment: Also to add, I don't really need `Options -MultiViews`. The rewrite works fine without that, but the issue with .php is still here.

Comment: I've got an idea for you. You have to add another separate rule for such things.

Comment: Yeah. Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.php [NC,L]`. Add these two lines and check it out and also don't remove `Options -MultiViews`. I provide you solutions as much as I could. Try those solutions and let me know.

Comment: I've added them, but no luck. I've edited the main thread to see it.

Comment: Oops. That's `%{REQUEST_URI}` not `%{REQUEST_URL}`. I'm sorry about that and don't edit the question with that.

Comment: Change it to `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Comment: You mean with `%{REQUEST_URL}`?

Comment: No, with `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: The line is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$` and it shows 500 Internal server error.

Comment: Oh. I'm looking into that.

Comment: Try adding those `#remove .php` two lines at the very end of the file and try it. Again, don't comment or remove `Options -MultiViews` option.

Comment: YES, that's it! I've moved the #remove .php lines to the bottom and now everything works great! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: You can edit your main post and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah. Done. Modified your `.htaccess` to show how it should look.